# How to register Known Types for serialization when using ASP.NET MVC Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, datacontractserializer

I have a ASP.NET MVC Web API controller that returns `public IEnumerable<IMessage> Get()`

It throws exception that I need to register types that derive from `IMessage` in known types collection passed to `DataContractSerializer`.

How to register "Known Types" for using with `DataContractSerializer` and `DataContractJSONSerializer` in MVC Web API project?

*KnownType attribute cannot be placed on interface.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the `KnownTypeAttribute` on your `IMessage` implementations:

```
public interface  IMessage
{
    string Content { get; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(Message))]
public class Message : IMessage {
    public string Content{ get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(Message2))]
public class Message2 : IMessage
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

So when calling the following action:

```
 public IEnumerable<IMessage> Get()
 {
     return new IMessage[] { new Message { Content = "value1" }, 
                             new Message2 { Content = "value2" } };
 }
```

The result will be this:

```
<ArrayOfanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <anyType xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MvcApplication3.Controllers" i:type="d2p1:Message">
        <d2p1:Content>value1</d2p1:Content>
    </anyType>
    <anyType xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MvcApplication3.Controllers" i:type="d2p1:Message2">
       <d2p1:Content>value2</d2p1:Content>
    </anyType>
</ArrayOfanyType>
```

But this will only work one "way". So you cannot post back the same XML.

In order to the following action should work:

```
public string Post(IEnumerable<IMessage> messages)
```

You need to register the known types globally, with configuring a `DataContractSerializer` and setting up in the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters`

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                   .Formatters
                   .XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<IEnumerable<IMessage>>(
                       new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<IMessage>), 
                           new[] { typeof(Message), typeof(Message2) }));
```

With using the configuration you don't need the `KnownTypeAttribute` on your implementation types.

Comment: Huh? putting [KnownType(Type)] on a Type itself looks weird to me, but i give it a try.

Comment: Strange, but it does work indeed but only in one side. I have a public void Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<IMessage> messages) method to which i then pass the stream, and messages always null, I'm using Fiddler for this maybe my post query is incorrect, or serializer can't read what it wrote.

Comment: Yeah, it is not working when you post back the same xml. I guess because of the `ArrayOfanyType` and `anyType`. I'm currently fiddling with it. I will get back to you if I find something.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev I've only managed to get it work on POST with introducing a wrapper class: `[KnownType(typeof(Message))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Message2))]
    public class MessagesHolder
    {
        public IEnumerable<IMessage> Messages { get; set; }
    }` then you only need to annotate this with `KnownType` and if you return `MessagesHolder` from Get you can post the XML back. I think the problem is that without the wrapper class there is no place to put the `KnownType` so it can't deserialize into a plain `IEnumerable<IMessage>` in the POST.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev beside the workaround what I posted as a comment, I've updated my answer with the "proper" solution.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the code for JSON is pretty much the same.